# Using python method in another module

Tags: python

I have a class created with methods i'm trying to call though another python module containing only a main function, its giving me a name 'unigueIDList is not defined' error. Shortened out code below

First module

```
class ClassObjects:
    def __init__(self, unigueIDList, nameList, priceList):
        self.ID = unigueIDList
        self.name = nameList
        self.price= priceList

    def uniqueId(self, list):
        unigueIDList= []
        [unigueIDList.append(item) for item in list 
        if item not in unigueIDList]
        self.ID.extend(unigueIDList)
        return unigueIDList

    def loadList(filename1, filename2):
        with open(filename1, "r") as csv1, open(filename2, "r") as csv2:  
            csvReader1 = csv.DictReader(csv1)
            csvReader2 = csv.DictReader(csv2)
            iDList = []
            for row1, row2 in zip(csvReader1, csvReader2):  
                idList.append((row2["Id"]))
            return iDList
```

Second module

```
def main()
    newTest = ClassObjects(unigueIDList, nameList, priceList)
    iDList = newTest.loadList(filename1, filename2)
    Id = newTest.uniqueId(iDList)
```

Comment: You need to create a new instance first. You are calling an instance method, not a static/class method.

Comment: @BramVanroy Thats what I was attempting with newTest = ClassObjects(iDList, nameList, priceList)

Comment: Is there a reason you are not calling `instance = ClassObjects(idList, [], [])` and then use the methods like the class designer intended?

Comment: @tripleee I attempted something similar to that and got a idList is not defined error when running it

Comment: If you are attempting to use a variable you haven't created, that's unrelated to your question. We can't really guess what these variables are supposed to mean or where they are coming from.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume you should build your instance first. How you're calling it now, without creating an instance first, you are just calling it as if it is a static method, but it is not, so your first argument is seen as `self` and your second argument is missing. Instead you need an initialised object first.

```
class ClassObjects:
    def __init__(self, iDList, nameList, priceList):
        self.ID = iDList
        self.name = nameList
        self.price= priceList

    def uniqueId(self, list):
        pass #empty definitions are forbidden
    def loadList(filename1, filename2):
        pass #empty definitions are forbidden
```

And main where you first create an instance

```
def main():
    # create instance with empty list properties
    clsObj = ClassObjects([], [], []) 
    # the values you pass through the methods need to be defined beforehand
    Id = clsObj.uniqueId(yourList)
    iDList = clsObj.loadList(someFilename, otherFilesname)
```

Comment: @kabanus I mentioned this in a comment, but I'll edit it in.

Comment: with this solution im getting , name 'iDList' is not defined, i'm defining it within Class1

Comment: Well, your constructor requires three properties, iDList, nameList, and priceList, so you have to ensure that you put the right values in there. The actual variable names of these lists that you need to construct your instance.

Comment: The correct variable names are definitely being used

Comment: Well according to Python they are not. Note that at `clsObj` the capital letters are different for `iDList` than they are on line `Id`: `idList`. Probably a typo in your code.

Comment: I double checked and copy and pasted the same variables from the _init_ method from Class1. I updated my question to try and make varible names more clear

Comment: The problem stays the same: you haven't defined the variables `unigueIDList`, `nameList`, `priceList` that you try to use in your constructor: `newTest = ClassObjects(unigueIDList, nameList, priceList)`. The values that you pass to the constructor `ClassObjects` are not defined.

Comment: How would I define them without overwriting whats being stored in them in Class1?

Comment: What? That doesn't make sense. It doesn't seem like you have any experience with classes or constructors. The value that you pass in the constructor creates an object with the values that you passed to it. If this isn't clear, I urge to go through some OO Python tutorials.

Comment: Whats confusing me here is, if I'm declaring and passing values though Class1 to say unigueIDList. When I create a instance of the class in main()  shouldn't it already be defined?

Comment: You are *not* declaring values or passing values at all. When you 'create' an instance, you need to pass a value to that to fill it. However, if you want to start with empty values, use empty lists: `clsObject = ClassObjects([], [], [])`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is truth that you have not defined idList. Please try this:

```
def main()
    idList=[]
    Id = ClassObjects.uniqueId(idList)
```

If the problem solved, you have not defined idList

Comment: idList in being created inside loadlist

Comment: Please show the code which you define idList. Also is main() is a method of loadlist?

Comment: @No loadlist() is a method in Class1, Main is outside of the class in a seperate module

Comment: Then, you have to link to idList. Something likes Class1.idList

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is an elegant solution, but you can try inputting the Class name as an argument while calling the function.

```
ClassObjects.uniqueId(ClassObjects,idList)
```